# Jquery number counter combines in string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I got those numbers working but the letter "T" has been replaced so that it won't show. Do you guys have any idea of how to get it works. Thank you very much.

```js
function commaSeparateNumber(val){
   while (/(\d+)(\d{3})/.test(val.toString())){
     val = val.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
   }
   return val;
 }

$('.number').each(function () {
  $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
      Counter: $(this).text()
  }, {
      duration: 8000,
      easing: 'swing',
      step: function (now) {
          $(this).text(commaSeparateNumber(Math.ceil(now)));
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="count"><div class="number">30</div></div>
<div class="text">text 1</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="count"><div class="number">3000</div></div>
<div class="text">text 2</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="count"><div class="number">700<span>T</span></div></div>
<div class="text">text 3</div>
```

Comment: have you tried just moving the span with "T" outside of the div.number?

Comment: I have tried that but i want the span inside the div.number

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Is this a continuation on some other question?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code was it was replacing whole the DOM structure include span containing 'T' so DOM structure has been updated.
Here is your updated code

```js
function commaSeparateNumber(val){
   while (/(\d+)(\d{3})/.test(val.toString())){
     val = val.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
   }
   return val;
 }

$('.number').each(function () {
  $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
      Counter: $(this).text()
  }, {
      duration: 8000,
      easing: 'swing',
      step: function (now) {
          $(this).text(commaSeparateNumber(Math.ceil(now)));
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="count"><div><span class="number">30</div></div>
<div class="text">text 1</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="count"><div><span class="number">3000</span></div></div>
<div class="text">text 2</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="count"><div><span class="number">700</span><span>T</span></div></div>
<div class="text">text 3</div>
```

Comment: ok. Thanks. By the way, how to add a space between 700T and ```8,000 -> 8 000```? . I have tried to replace the  "," besides the $1 with a space like ```&nbsp;```, but it does not work.

Comment: you could adjust the "space" with css margins `.t {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.count {
  text-align: right;
  width: 100px;
}` or simply add a space character infront of the <span>t</span>